# Can't have Authorized Axios post request to Raindrop API

Tags: api, request, axios, http-post

I'm trying to build a simple fetch app for one of my raindrop collection and display it on a project.

I'm using a "Test Token" so I don't have to make all the authorization stuff for now.

All the informations (access_token, collection_id) displays well.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (accessToken !== null) {
        const headers = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        };

        axios.post(
            `https://api.raindrop.io/rest/v1/collection/${COLLECTION_ID}`,
            { headers: headers }
        ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
    }
},[])
```

The headers I'm injecting are displayed in Request Payload in the https

[image: Http resquest headers]

But the response just displays Unauthorized...

Is someone has ever tried to do this and can help me with it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Axios post request, 2nd parameter is body and 3rd is headers.

Change your request to,

```js
        axios.post(
            `https://api.raindrop.io/rest/v1/collection/${COLLECTION_ID}`,
            {}, // request body, since post request.
            { headers: headers }
        ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```